# \tikzmark in \foreach loop problem

Tags: foreach, tikzmark

The use of `\tikzmark` in a `\foreach` loop leads to this error message :

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   \tikzmark ...reid \@undefined \let \tikzmark@next 
>                                                     =\tikzmark@outside \else > ...
>
> l.45 \TabTikzMark*{3}
>                      \hline

with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,array,xparse}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcounter{TabTikzCount}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\TabTikzMark}{sm}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \\[-\ht\@arstrutbox]\noalign{\setcounter{TabTikzCount}{1}}%
        \Row{3}
        \\[-\dp\@arstrutbox]%
        }{%
        \\[-\ht\@arstrutbox]
        \Row{3}
        \\[-\dp\@arstrutbox]}}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\Row}[1]{
    \xdef\MyRow{{\Alph{TabTikzCount}0}}
    \foreach \n [evaluate=\n as \m using int(\n-1)] in {2,...,#1} {%
    %\xdef\MyRow{\MyRow\strut\hfill\Alph{TabTikzCount}\m&}
    \xdef\MyRow{\MyRow\strut\hfill\tikzmark{\Alph{TabTikzCount}\m}&}
    }%
    %\MyRow\hfill\Alph{TabTikzCount}#1%
    \MyRow\hfill\tikzmark{\Alph{TabTikzCount}#1}%
    \stepcounter{TabTikzCount}}

\begin{document}


essai

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\TabTikzMark*{3}\hline
a&z&a\TabTikzMark{3}\hline
a&z&a\TabTikzMark{3}\hline
\end{tabular}

essai

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw[->] (pic cs:A1) -- (pic cs:B2) ;

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try preventing the expansion?

Comment: using `\expandafter` ? Yes I try, but one is not enought useless, even for a single turn in the loop. I mean as at each turn \MyRow is expanded, the firt tikzmak need more \expandafter that the last tikzmark ?

Comment: `\expandafter` does not prevent expansion (rather the opposite) you  probably want `\let\tikzmark\relax`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This avoids pre-expanding `\tikzmark` and runs without error but you do not say what result you want, I am not sure if this was the intended output

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,array,xparse}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcounter{TabTikzCount}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\TabTikzMark}{sm}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \\[-\ht\@arstrutbox]\noalign{\setcounter{TabTikzCount}{1}}%
        \Row{3}
        \\[-\dp\@arstrutbox]%
        }{%
        \\[-\ht\@arstrutbox]
        \Row{3}
        \\[-\dp\@arstrutbox]}}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\Row}[1]{%
    \xdef\MyRow{{\Alph{TabTikzCount}0}}%
    \foreach \n [evaluate=\n as \m using int(\n-1)] in {2,...,#1} {%
    \let\tikzmark\relax
    %\xdef\MyRow{\MyRow\strut\hfill\Alph{TabTikzCount}\m&}%
    \xdef\MyRow{\MyRow\strut\hfill\tikzmark{\Alph{TabTikzCount}\m}&}%
    }%
    %\MyRow\hfill\Alph{TabTikzCount}#1%
    \MyRow\hfill\tikzmark{\Alph{TabTikzCount}#1}%
    \stepcounter{TabTikzCount}}

\begin{document}


essai

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\TabTikzMark*{3}\hline
a&z&a\TabTikzMark{3}\hline
a&z&a\TabTikzMark{3}\hline
\end{tabular}

essai

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw[->] (pic cs:A1) -- (pic cs:B2) ;

\end{document}
```